# Why does my VBA code throw the Runtime Error 1004 when I am trying to have a button on another worksheet run this macro? Below is the code processed

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code I want to run. I want to be able to click a button on one page and have the other page run this on the pivot table. I will also include the code for the button, which actually my be what is causing the issue.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call OHPivot_Store80
End Sub

Sub OHPivot_Store80()
    '
    ' OHPivot_Store80 Macro
    '
    
    '
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("StoreNumber").CurrentPage _
            = "(All)"
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("StoreNumber")
            .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("6").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("22").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("24").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("40").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("44").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("48").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("50").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("54").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("56").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("58").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("60").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("62").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("64").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("70").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("72").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("74").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("76").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("78").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("82").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("84").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("86").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("88").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("90").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("92").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("94").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("96").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("98").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("110").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Because the `ActiveSheet` isn't what you think it is?

Answer (score 1):

Change the code that responds to the button click to active the sheet that has the pivot table as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Worksheets.Activate("NAME_OF_SHEET_WITH_PIVOT_TABLE")
    Call OHPivot_Store80
End Sub
```